# glade(GTK) creating and compiling code for windows

Tags: windows, gtk, glade

I want to develop a small application using glade/gtk on and for Windows XP 
and I also want to get some C code into it.
 I have tried lot of things like [MinGW](http://www.ibiblio.org/apollo/WinGtkHowto.html), but have not made any progress.

Can some one please tell me some simple steps that I should follow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some instructions: http://www.gtkforums.com/about894.html